# How to encoding a string into a bytearray using utf-8?

Tags: python, arrays, string, utf-8, encode

I want to encode a string in a byte array using utf-8. For example, for the string `"CD"` I want to obtain `b"\x43\x44"`. I have tried this, but it's not working:

```
def toTab(strMessage):
    return strMessage.encode('utf-8')
```

and I get `b'CD'`, which is not the result I want.

Comment: `b'\x43\x44'` and `b'CD'` are the same byte string, just written differently. Check this expression: `b'\x43\x44' == b'CD'`. It's like writing `3.0` or `3.00000` or `3e0` for all the same number.

Answer (score 2):

One of the major changes from Python 2 to 3 was with the str data type. More about that [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/strings-unicode-and-bytes-in-python-3-everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-27dc02ff2686). Basically, they try their hardest to be human readable at all times, which can lead to some interesting and frustrating things when trying to keep hex values in a string. The b in front of a string tells python that it is encoded, so your function actually is working, but it is displayed as human readable. To show this, simply try:

```
b'CD'.hex()
```

or, more specifically:

```
'CD'.encode().hex()
```

which gives:

```
'4344'
```

EDIT: To clarify, a python `str` will always represent ASCII as ASCII. This can be shown by entering the following into a console:

```
"résumé".encode("utf-8")
```

which will yield:

```
b'r\xc3\xa9sum\xc3\xa9'
```

Notice that all ASCII is rendered as such and non-ASCI is represented by bytes. Also notice something key, UTF-8 characters can be represented with anything form 1 to 4 bytes (where a byte is 8 bits). The entire ASCII set on the other hand can be represented with only 7 bits, leaving all ASCII bytes zero padded.

So again, your output is `b'\x43\x44'`, it is just visually represented as `b'CD'`. If you passed this to a c program to, say, exploit a buffer overflow, it recognizes the string as `b'\x43\x44'` as you desire.

To show this, try:

```
if b'\x43\x44' == b'CD':
    print(True, b'\x43\x44')
else:
    print(False)
```

Which will print: `True b'CD'`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I get what you say. Actually I wanted to get b"\x43\x44", but it's okay. The most important is that i understand what Python is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You could get what you want by combining and formatting each byte of the bytearray manually.

```
def toTab(strMessage):
    return 'b"{}"'.format(''.join(r'\x{:0x}'.format(b) for b in strMessage))

msg = b"\x43\x44"
print(toTab(msg))  # -> b"\x43\x44"
```

Comment: But this does not do what the OP wants, as you are putting in a byte array. If you already have the byte array, why not just use it, rather than putting in a function to get the same thing out?

Comment: @jacob: Perhaps I misunderstood what the OP meant by "I want to obtain `b"\x43\x44"` — which I took to mean literally a string with exactly those characters in it.